# Using sqldf in python 2, getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code is shown below:

```
pip install pandasql

import pandasql as pdsql

str1="select * from data5 limit 5;" 


df11=pdsql.sqldf(str1)
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

```
Error:   

 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-55-316d12745a46> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df11=pdsql.sqldf(str1)


C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.pyc in sqldf(query, env, db_uri)
    154     >>> sqldf("select avg(x) from df;", locals())
    155     """
--> 156     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.pyc in __call__(self, query, env)
     45         """
     46         if env is None:
---> 47             env = get_outer_frame_variables()
     48 
     49         with self.conn as conn:

C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.pyc in get_outer_frame_variables()
     95     cur_filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
     96     outer_frame = next(f
---> 97                        for f in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())
     98                        if f.filename != cur_filename)
     99     variables = {}

C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.pyc in <genexpr>((f,))
     96     outer_frame = next(f
     97                        for f in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())
---> 98                        if f.filename != cur_filename)
     99     variables = {}
    100     variables.update(outer_frame.frame.f_globals)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Comment: This might have to do with your version of `sqlpf`. Try upgrading to the latest version using `pip install sqlpdf --upgrade`.

Comment: hi adeel , im getting error as                                                       
 Collecting sqlpdf
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlpdf (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sqlpdf

Comment: maybe unrelated but `pip install pandasql` is something you run from the command line, not in python code

Comment: (C:\py) C:\python>pip install pandasql
Requirement already satisfied: pandasql in c:\py\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\py\lib\site-packages (from pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in c:\py\lib\site-packages (from pandasql)

Comment: it show requirment already satisfied,but still i was not able to query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandasql as pdsql`

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
res = pysqldf(your_query)
```

I hope it helps.